# Obtener datos combinados de MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  rol varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Donde en la tabla ‘usuarios’ puede hacer 2 tipos de usuarios con diferentes roles: ‘profesor’ y ‘alumno’.

Además, en la tabla ‘users_subjects’, se relacionan las asignaturas con los usuarios.

En mi código, cuando hace login un usuario cuyo rol es ‘profesor’ y tiene asignaturas X, se muestra una tabla con todos los usuarios cuyo rol es ‘alumno’ y todas las asignaturas que tienen.

Me gustaría hacer un SELECT donde solo se pueda ver en la tabla a los alumnos cuya asignaturas son iguales que las del ‘profesor’ registrado (da igual si es una o varias asignaturas)

Estoy intentando hacerlo con los siguientes SELECT pero no sale bien:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM users
where rol = 'alumno'
and id in (
    select distinct u.id 
    from users u, users_subjects us, subjects e
    where u.username='".$_SESSION['username']."'
    and us.user_id_fk=u.id 
    and e.subject_id=us.subject_id_fk
);";


$sql = "SELECT *
FROM users u
JOIN users_subjects us ON (us.user_id_fk = u.id)
JOIN subjects s ON (s.subject_id = us.subject_id_fk)
WHERE u.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
AND u.rol = 'alumno'";
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que necesitas relacionar la tabla *users* (y la *user_subjects*) dos veces: una para el profesor, otra para los alumnos. Al hacer el WHERE, estás filtrando para que el mismo registro de esa tabla tenga el *username* del profesor y el *username* del alumno (lo cual por tu descripción no es posible)

```
SELECT *
FROM users uProf
    JOIN users_subjects usProf ON (usProf.user_id_fk = uProf.id)
    JOIN subjects s ON (s.subject_id = usProf.subject_id_fk)
    JOIN users_subjects usAlu ON (s.subject_id = usAlu.subject_id_fk)
    JOIN users uAlu ON (usAlu.user_id_fk = uAlu.id)
WHERE uProf.username = [usernameProfesor]
    AND uAlu.rol = 'alumno';
```

y dado que s.subject_id coincide, se puede simplificar:

```
SELECT *
FROM users uProf
    JOIN users_subjects usProf ON (usProf.user_id_fk = uProf.id)
    JOIN users_subjects usAlu ON (usProf.subject_id_fk = usAlu.subject_id_fk)
    JOIN users uAlu ON (usAlu.user_id_fk = uAlu.id)
WHERE uProf.username = [usernameProfesor]
    AND uAlu.rol = 'alumno';
```

Dicho lo dicho, que la relación de una persona con una materia dependa de su "clase" (profesor o alumno) puede ser problemático... ¿Que pasa si el profesor de filosofía se apunta a clases de programación? O que el alumno que se graduó hace tres años ahora sea profesor... ¿le borras el historial?

Lo más normal sería que hubiera una relación "da clase" distinta de "recibe clase" (o que si solo hay una relación, haya un atributo indicando cuál es la relación, pero eso ya es más sucio).

Comment: +1 ... ¿Que pasa si el profesor de filosofía se apunta a clases de programación? O que el alumno que se graduó hace tres años ahora sea profesor...

Comment: Funciona perfecto Juan! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Tendré en cuenta tus suposiciones sobre qué pasaría si... en la asignatura, no se me había ocurrido.